# Position of elements inside object

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting, object

I have an object (lets call it myObject) that is build like this (if you console.log it)

```
>Object {info1: Object, info2: Object, info3: Object, info4: Object,…}
      >info1: Object
      >info2: Object
      Id: 532
      someParam: true
      >info3: Object
      >info4: Object
      Id_secondary: 222
```

If you check the inside of info1,info2  (objects inside main object) their structure goes similar to this:

```
Aparameter: "random info"
Cparameter: "something"
LParameter: "other data"
Surname: "Random Surname"
Username: "Name test"
```

What bothers me is that they are in alphabetical order.

If I for instance go iterate trough this given object I can see that data inside info1, info2 (object inside the main object) is not ordered alphabetically. 
I check this with:

```
for (var k in myObject)
    if (typeof myObject[k] !== 'function') {
        if(k == 'info1' || k == 'info2' || k == 'info3' || k == 'info4'){
            for (var j in myObject[k]){
                if (typeof myObject[k][j] !== 'function' && k == 'info1') {
                     console.log("Key is " + j + ", value is " + myObject[k][j]);
                }
            }
            // HERE this objects' data are in correct order !   
            console.log(myObject[k]);  <------------------------- see this
        }
    }       
}
```

How can I retain the position of the data inside objects in myObject?

Any help appreciated

Comment: There is no order to an object. If you need order you should use an array instead.

Comment: I don't think objects retain any order of the entries stored in them. If you want an ordered data structure, you must use a list. If it's just about printing/logging the objects in alphabetical order, make a list of the property names, sort that, and then log the values.

Comment: Thanks for commenting. Unfortunately I need to have this object since I am just updating a production environment (also unfortunately for me). So I must convert to array, sort and then convert back to object? ahhh, no easier way?

Answer (score 0):

The keys in objects are stored in the order they are added. AFAIK this is an "unofficial" feature added to browsers for programmers' convenience, and I wouldn't advise relying on it.

Comment: thanks for your answer. I ended up using an array and another one for hashing position ...